# Job Reposted on Linkedin After an Update From Manager

Tags: interviewing, job-search, linkedin

I have been interviewing with this company for about a month now. 
It started with an initial interview with their HR and they told me right away it might take them a while to get back to me since a lot of people are on vacations. 
Two weeks later I got an email with tasks from the department manager. I solved the tasks and sent them back. 
After that they contacted me, saying  they want me to have an interview to meet the team. 
 That went really well in my opinion. 
At the end, they told me again that the process is going to be slow due to multiple people being on holidays. 
And today, a little bit of a shock. 
First, I got an email from the department manager that I interviewed with and was present at the team interview basically saying "Hey, we just want to keep you in the loop, the team really liked you, but we are  still interviewing other candidates, we will let you know more soon" 
A few hours later, I went on Linkedin and was surprised to see that the job I am interviewing for was just posted again. After the ad had already gone down a week or so ago.

  
What do you make of that? 
 Is this normal? 
 Why would they not tell me so if they are looking to hire other people? Especially knowing their process is really slow. 
 
 
 **Update** (in case anyone cares): The company ended up offering me the position a week later. I didn't end up accepting it because I got a much better offer from another company a few days before that. 
 Thanks everyone for your input!

Comment: "*but we are still interviewing other candidates*" Isn't that them telling you they are looking at other people?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What do you make of that? Is this normal? Why would they not tell me
> so if they are looking to hire other people? Especially knowing their
> process is really slow.

Quite simply you didn't convince them to hire you on the spot. They may have liked you but not enough to give you the job without considering other candidates. it is pretty clear when they said:

> "Hey, we just want to keep you in the loop, the team really liked you,
> but we are still interviewing other candidates, we will let you know
> more soon"

that they want to keep shopping around and hopefully find someone more suited for the role they want to fill. This can easily include re-opening the add, though having it expire may just be an oversight in the first place.

And the unasked question:

> So what to do about it?

Nothing, just keep job hunting as you should do until you have signed a contract with a new employer. Keep poking this one for updates as, who knows, maybe eventually they will come through with an offer. But until that happens you should keep hunting.

Answer (score 0):

Their hiring process is very slow, because it is low priority. Most likely, they are not looking to hire someone unless he or she is a perfect, once in a lifetime fit. I don't know for sure, but my guess is that they are just trying to determine the number of potential employees, and how qualified they are for when they actually need somebody.

Don't take it personal. Try to keep track of companies that are seemingly constantly hiring, by saving their past postings on Linkedin. If you happen to apply to one of these companies, adjust your expectations.